# DISC vs MBTI personality types research

Tags: personality, big-five, mbti

I Wanted to know whether there has been any research on mbti and disc personalty mapping and the correlations between them.If so can anyone link to some research papers

Comment: https://internalchange.com/wp-content/uploads/PPSMBO-231.pdf or https://www.psychometrics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/mbti_disc_comp.pdf Also https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1054970.pdf mentions DISC.

Comment: Related, mapping to big 5: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20431/21